# TabPageIndicator Text Font

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm using ViewPagerIndicator, and haven't had any luck, so I'll ask here. Is there a way to change the font for the Tabs in a TabPageIndicator?

Comment: This is just another method   http://stackoverflow.com/a/17747584/542532

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use an other third party lib in order to do this, you can modify the [TabView class(in TabPageIndicator)](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/TabPageIndicator.java) like this(this assuming you want the same font in your entire app):

```
private class TabView extends TextView {
    private int mIndex;

    public TabView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Re-measure if we went beyond our maximum size.
        if (mMaxTabWidth > 0 && getMeasuredWidth() > mMaxTabWidth) {
            super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMaxTabWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return mIndex;
    }

    public TabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TabView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf"); // setting a custom TypeFace
        setTypeface(tf);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use a third-party lib nor to change `ViewPagerIndicator` lib.

`TabPageIndicator` has a single `ViewGroup` child which contains the tab `View`s so you can use this code to change the font:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) indicator.getChildAt(0);
int vgChildCount = vg.getChildCount();
for (int j = 0; j < vgChildCount; j++) {
    View vgChild = vg.getChildAt(j);
    if (vgChild instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) vgChild).setTypeface(YOUR_FONT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've kind of brute forced my way into making it work, using a library called Oak (Where the TextViewWithFont is), and passing the PagerIndicator into this method:

```
private static void changeFonts(ViewGroup root, Activity a, String typeface) {
    Typeface tf = TextViewWithFont.getStaticTypeFace(a, typeface);

    for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(tf);
        } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            changeFonts((ViewGroup) v, a, typeface);
        }
    }
}
public static void setTabPageIndicatorFont(ViewGroup root, Activity a) {
    changeFonts(root, a, "DINCondBold.otf");
}
```

Oak if anyones interested: http://willowtreeapps.github.com/OAK/

If anyone has a better way to go about it, I'd love to get a second opinion.