# Using custom font in viewpagerindicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator, custom-font

In my project I am using the font android: fontFamily = "sans-serif-light", and working properly.

I am also using the library viewpagerindicator. I want to use the font android: fontFamily = "sans-serif-light" also in the viewpagerindicator, but can not find how to do it

I've tried using `android:fontFamily = "sans-serif-light"` in `<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator ...` and in style, but without success.

I have also tried:

```
PageIndicator mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById (R.id.indicator);
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset (getAssets (), "fonts / Roboto-Light.ttf");
mIndicator.setTypeface (myTypeface);
```

but this does not work ..

I appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards

Comment: See the solution I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21786373/752781

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I don't get you wrong, you want to change titles font in view pager indicator,

I changed the library to achieve that,
for TabPageIndicator custome typeface I added this for TabPageIndicator.java

```
private Typeface                       mTypeface;
public void setTypeFace(Typeface tf) {
    this.mTypeface = tf;
    }
```

and then change addTab function to this:

```
    private void addTab(int index, CharSequence text, int iconResId) {
final TabView tabView = new TabView(getContext());
tabView.mIndex = index;
tabView.setFocusable(true);
tabView.setOnClickListener(mTabClickListener);
tabView.setText(text);


**if (mTypeface != null) {
    tabView.setTypeface(mTypeface);
}**


if (iconResId != 0) {
    tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconResId, 0, 0, 0);
}

mTabLayout.addView(tabView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, MATCH_PARENT, 1));
}
```

now you should just setTypeFace on your tabpagerindicator, like this:

```
mTabPageIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.tab_page_indicator);
mTabPageIndicator.setTypeFace(Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/custome_font.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library, here's how I did it (index is the tab index in your view page indicator):

```
private void changeTabText(int index, boolean on){
    if(tabLayout.getChildCount()-1 >= index){
        TextView tv = (TextView)tabLayout.getChildAt(index);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(on? android.R.color.black : R.color.light_grey));
        CustomFont.setTypeface(tv, CustomFont.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Here's how I got the tablayout:

```
tabLayout = (ViewGroup)indicator.getChildAt(0); //indicator is a horizontal scroll view, there will be only one root layout
```

Here's what my custom font does:

```
 public static void setTypeface(TextView view, String font) {
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), BASE_PATH + font);
    view.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more OOD implementation is to modify the Library by creating a new interface:

```
public interface FontPagerAdapter {
/**
 * Get the fonts to set.
 */
Typeface getCustomFont();}
```

And in class TabPageIndicator.java add a new property:

```
private Typeface customTypeFace;
```

which will be set in the notifyDataSetChanged() method by declaring:

```
if (adapter instanceof FontPagerAdapter) {
        FontPagerAdapter fontAdapter = (FontPagerAdapter)adapter;
        customTypeFace = fontAdapter.getCustomFont();
    }
```

Later you would change the Font by setting it programatically in the addTab method, just by adding:

```
if (customTypeFace != null) {
   tabView.setTypeface(customTypeFace);
}
```

Finally in the adapter that will use the library, you need to implement this interface, then override the method:

```
@Override
public Typeface getCustomFont() {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/PoetsenOne-Regular.ttf");
    return font;
}
```