# How to Change TabPageIndicator Text Style - Bold , TextSize at selected?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

[Hear I found Jake Wharton blog which includes some changes in Viewpager indicator styles](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/71)

I want Make Changes while selecting the Tab Text Get Larger than Default and Bold

using this main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and

style.xml

> 

```
<style name="Theme.VPI" parent="Theme.Styled">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>
<!-- "Implementation" of our ABS custom theme -->
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- "Implementation" of VPI theme. We just set the text size and color.TabPageIndicator -->
<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:textStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:animateOnClick">true</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tab_text_style</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
</style>
<!-- More customizations for ABS  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> -->
<style name="TitleText" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

and in drawbale tab_text_style.xml

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/tab_text_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="@color/tab_text_unselected" />
</selector>
```

my tabs looks like this, I am Using ViewPagerIndicator wiht ActionBarSherlock

[image: First Default Tab]

[image: second selected Tab]

I want To Look Like This...

[image: image one selected]

[image: image two selected]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: wonder if there is a way to do that, but you could experiment around with the styles for the tab view :)

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille Yep I tried Several things... using Stackoverlflow...but didn't get helped to control over text on tab..

Comment: hmm then may be it is not possible unless you use the deprecated tabhost and tab indicators of your own :). And **Your link is broken**

Comment: nothing i am not using them i am using Viewpager indicator styles

Comment: refer to [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/196) may be you could create two styles, one for when selected and one for when not selected. i dont know if at runtime it is possible to switch between the styles but you could give it a try and get back'

Comment: hey, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228186/tabpageindicator-text-font) too